# Vertically aligned item using line-height is slightly off middle

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In this style of using line-height and inline-block, why is the green item a **few pixels below the middle**? Shouldn't there be exactly 15px above and below?

```css
.container{
  height: 45px; 
  line-height: 45px; 
  background-color: red; 
  display: inline-block
}

.item{
  height: 15px; 
  width: 15px; 
  background-color: green; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

I know there are other ways of vertically aligning items (including JS, absolute positions, and many more). I'm not trying to solve the general "how to vertically align a div".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit here is not so much the `line-height`, but rather the `vertical-align: middle`. It tries to align your box with the text that may hypothetically be inside the parent box. Where the inner box ends up depends on the `font-size` of that text. You can push the box further down by increasing the font-size of its parent:

```css
.container{
  height: 45px; 
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 45px; 
  font-size: 45px;
  background-color: red; 
  display: inline-block
}

.item{
  height: 15px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: green; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
job
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the text is closer to the bottom of its container than to the top (the "j" overflows the container while the "b" does not).

In the same way, you can move the box closer to the center by decreasing the `font-size`. Since you asked in comments, here's how you get it optimally centered with this method: Set `font-size` to 0 on the container.

```css
.container{
  height: 45px; 
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 45px; 
  font-size: 0px;
  background-color: red; 
  display: inline-block
}

.item{
  height: 15px; 
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: green; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
job
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not asking about text. And the green box in your code snippet is not centered as well.

Comment: You asked why the box is not centered. This is the reason. The box in my example is *less* centered than your box because I increased the font size. And line-height works the same way whether or not there is any text.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm accepting this - can you please edit it so it focuses on the font-size?

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your style may help you

```
.container {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.item {
    background-color: #008000;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's another solution that works. I edited my question to clarify that the issue is with inline-block elements. table-cell is something else entirely...

Answer (score -2):

Please use dividable size to make this work. Also remove vertical align attribue

https://jsfiddle.net/guc6uxc7/

```
.container{
 height: 42px; 
 line-height: 42px; 
 background-color: red; 
 display: inline-block
 }

 .item{
 height: 12px; 
 width: 12px; 
 background-color: green; 
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: not even centered